# Cannot receive UDP packets from app run via Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, windows-8, udp, scheduled-tasks

I created a small C# app with Visual Studio 2012 that I want to use messages with to another app.  This app uses UI Automation to grab text from another running app.  I need to run this as an administrator because otherwise it cannot grab the text I need since that other app apparently runs under an adminstrator account as well.

My client app needs to run under any account, elevated or unelevated, hence the reason why I separated the admin part from it.  The idea was to get the info I needed from the app granted admin rights and broadcast it to the other app via UDP.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work out so well.

If I open both tasks via Explorer it works, but if I open the listener/client app myself using Explorer and try to have the admin portion run automatically via Task Scheduler I never see the broadcasts.  I set it up to run both on start and on logon and have specified an admin username/password.  I can see the admin app running in Task Manager but don't get the UDP broadcasts.

My understanding is that apps started through Task Scheduler don't have UI access, but are their local socket communications blocked as well?